# How do I get the "selected" instance of an ItemsControl DataTemplate?

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, windows-runtime, windows-8.1

I created a dynamic form that allows a user to add a variation of an item using ItemsControl.

```
                    <ItemsControl x:Name="variationItemsControl"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding FormItem.Variations}"
                              Visibility="Collapsed">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width=".60*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width=".30*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,1,0">
                                    <TextBlock
                                        Foreground="White"
                                        Text="Variation Name"/>
                                    <TextBox
                                        x:Name="variationName"
                                        Style="{StaticResource FlyoutField}"
                                        Text="{Binding VariationName, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
                                    <TextBlock
                                        Foreground="White"
                                        Text="Price"/>
                                    <TextBox
                                        Style="{StaticResource FlyoutField}"
                                        Text="{Binding VariationPrice, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                                <Button 
                                    Grid.Column="2" 
                                    Margin="0,0,0,6" 
                                    Content="X" 
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                    Click="deleteVariationButton_Click"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
```

In the Grid, there is a button which, when clicked, I am hoping will remove that template instance. For example, in the following image, if I click on the 'X' button of the 12 oz. item, that item should be removed.

[image]

It's a simple matter of removing that instance from the ItemsControl's ItemsSource, but I need to know how to do that in the 'X' buttons click event. The object sender is the button itself, and RoutedEventArgs doesn't seem to contain any relevant information I can use.

```
private void deleteVariationButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // what do I do here?      
}
```

Is there anyway to get the index of the template container that the 'X' button I clicked on resides? If I can just get that index, then it's a simple removal from the ItemsControl's ItemsSource container.

EDIT More Code:

```
public class Item : ObservableObject, IEquatable<Item>
{
    private string itemName;
    public string ItemName
    {
        get { return itemName; }
        set { Set<string>(() => ItemName, ref itemName, value.ToString().Trim()); }
    }

    private Category itemCategory;
    public Category ItemCategory
    {
        get { return itemCategory; }
        set { Set<Category>(() => ItemCategory, ref itemCategory, value); }
    }

    private decimal? singlePrice;
    public decimal? SinglePrice
    {
        get { return singlePrice; }
        set { Set<decimal?>(() => SinglePrice, ref singlePrice, value); }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Variation> variations;
    public ObservableCollection<Variation> Variations
    {
        get { return variations; }
        set { Set<ObservableCollection<Variation>>(() => Variations, ref variations, value); }
    }

    private bool hasVariations;
    public bool HasVariations
    {
        get { return hasVariations; }
        set { Set<bool>(() => HasVariations, ref hasVariations, value); }
    }

    public Item()
    {
        itemCategory = new Category();
        Variations = new ObservableCollection<Variation>();
    }

    public Item(Item other)
    {
        Copy(other);
    }

    public void Copy(Item other)
    {
        if (this != other)
        {
            ItemName = other.ItemName;
            ItemCategory = new Category();
            ItemCategory.CategoryName = other.ItemCategory.CategoryName;
            ItemCategory.CategoryColor = other.ItemCategory.CategoryColor;
            SinglePrice = other.SinglePrice;
            Variations = new ObservableCollection<Variation>();

            foreach (Variation v in other.variations)
            {
                variations.Add(new Variation(v));
            }
        }
    }

    public bool Equals(Item other)
    {
        if (variations.Count() != other.variations.Count())
            return false;

        for (int i = 0; i < variations.Count(); i++)
        {
            if (!variations.ElementAt(i).Equals(other.variations.ElementAt(i)))
                return false;
        }

        if (itemName == other.itemName &&
            itemCategory.CategoryName == other.itemCategory.CategoryName &&
            itemCategory.CategoryColor == other.itemCategory.CategoryColor &&
            singlePrice == other.singlePrice &&
            hasVariations == other.hasVariations)
            return true;

        return false;
    }

    public class Variation : ObservableObject
    {
        public RelayCommand DeleteVariationCommand { get; private set; }

        private string variationName;
        public string VariationName
        {
            get { return variationName; }
            set { Set<string>(() => VariationName, ref variationName, value.ToString().Trim()); }
        }

        private decimal? variationPrice;
        public decimal? VariationPrice
        {
            get { return variationPrice; }
            set { Set<decimal?>(() => VariationPrice, ref variationPrice, value); }
        }

        public Variation()
        {
            variationName = "";
            variationPrice = 0M;

            DeleteVariationCommand = new RelayCommand(
                () => DeleteVariation(),
                () => CanDeleteVariation());
        }

        public void DeleteVariation()
        {

        }

        public bool CanDeleteVariation()
        {
            return true;
        }

        public Variation(Variation other)
        {
            variationName = other.variationName;
            variationPrice = other.variationPrice;
        }

        public bool Equals(Variation other)
        {
            if (variationName.Equals(other.variationName) && variationPrice == other.variationPrice)
                return true;

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try to get the grid selected row index and delete it

Comment: The Variation item class should expose a Delete command, which deletes it from the `FormItem.Variations` collection. Instead of having a Button Click handler, you would bind the Button's `Command` property to the Delete command.

Comment: @Clemens: Thanks. You've set me on the right path. The command can only be accessed in the FormItem.Variations class, but the problem is that my Variations class is nested in the Item class, so I can't access the Variations collection to remove a variation from unless it's static, which it cannot be in my situation, since every item needs its own Variations collection. I can't seem to find a way. I've added my Item class code to the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind to the command property of the button instead of using a routed event. If you do that, you can use the RelativeSource property of the binding to find the item's ItemsControl parent, which should have the DataContext of the list containing the item to be deleted.

Have the CommandParameter set to {Binding} so that the delete command knows which item to remove from the list.

You can do something like this for the command binding on the delete button:

```
<Button x:Name="buttonDelete"
        Command="{Binding ElementName="MyItemsControl", Path=DataContext.DeleteItemCommand}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
```

Comment: Except that `Mode=FindAncestor` is not available in Windows Runtime. I'd suggest to replace that by an `ElementName` binding. Also, the command would probably be moved to the FormItem class (which holds the Variations property), and the path would therefore be `Path=DataContext.FormItem.DeleteItemCommand`.

Comment: Didn't realize that the FindAncestor mode doesn't work in Windows Runtime. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Clemens, thank you so much! Thank you CrumblyRock. It's working now.